# Where does TexLive install fonts on Windows?

Tags: fonts, texlive

If I install TexLive on Windows 7, will the fonts be shared with Windows system so that other softwares like Adobe Illustrator can have access to them? If the answer is no, how can the fonts be shared with other softwares?

Comment: There should be a `fonts` folder in `texlive/<year>/texmf-dist/`.

Comment: If you open up the font folder in your window, you can select and install fonts from its subdirectories. (You probably want to install for all users.) However, Windows does not automatically update font files as TeX Live does.

Comment: note however that most classic tex fonts (especially math fonts) are in custom tex-specific encodings so not easily usable in other software. This doesn't apply to the opentype fonts used with luatex/xetex.